# How do I make a fixed BG image overflow out of parent DIV?

Tags: css, html, position, fixed

I have a container DIV that houses a child div, and within the child div I have 5 sections. I want section 2 and 4 to have a fixed background image, so that when I scroll than the image will stay still. I want to reproduce the very cool almost-parallax effect of article scrolling that can be seen here: http://www.polygon.com/2013/1/17/3882754/oswald-epic-mickey-disney

However, the background image remains WITHIN the parent div! I can't get it to overflow out of it for some reason. I'd really appreciate all the help!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head> 
<style>
html, body, 
.container,
.cbp-fbscroller,
.cbp-fbscroller section { 
    height: 100%; 
}
 .cbp-fbscroller section {
    position: relative;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
 #fbsection2 {
    background-image: url(http://solarle.cdn2.cafe24.com/tistory/i-beautiful.jpg);
}
 #fbsection4 {
    background-image: url(http://solarle.cdn2.cafe24.com/tistory/geek2.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
<div style="width: 700px">
<div id="cbp-fbscroller" class="cbp-fbscroller">
    <section id="fbsection1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut massa ac mauris dictum porttitor quis in libero. Etiam orci nulla, placerat eget sagittis ut, porta a dolor. Duis ac lacinia libero. Integer fermentum erat eget urna mollis tristique. Mauris et sapien leo. Suspendisse et lorem eget massa consectetur elementum eu ac neque. Nunc eu nisl tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque tristique, arcu sit amet commodo euismod, leo dolor sagittis ante, et fermentum nisi felis eu ipsum. Phasellus id elit lacus. Ut eget nisi non sapien tincidunt tristique eget vel neque. Nullam mi ipsum, blandit eget posuere a, mattis fermentum nunc. In a eros eget dui semper scelerisque a non neque. Curabitur aliquet tempus venenatis. Nam ante turpis, tincidunt at tristique vel, scelerisque ut libero.</p>

</section>

    <section id="fbsection2">
<br />
<blockquote class="bigquote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut massa ac mauris dictum porttitor quis in libero. Etiam orci nulla, placerat eget sagittis ut, porta a dolor. Duis ac lacinia libero. Integer fermentum erat eget urna mollis tristique. Mauris et sapien leo. Suspendisse et lorem eget massa consectetur elementum eu ac neque. Nunc eu nisl tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque tristique, arcu sit amet commodo euismod, leo dolor sagittis ante, et fermentum nisi felis eu ipsum. Phasellus id elit lacus. Ut eget nisi non sapien tincidunt tristique eget vel neque. Nullam mi ipsum, blandit eget posuere a, mattis fermentum nunc. In a eros eget dui semper scelerisque a non neque. Curabitur aliquet tempus venenatis. Nam ante turpis, tincidunt at tristique vel, scelerisque ut libero.</blockquote>
<br />
</section>

    <section id="fbsection3">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut massa ac mauris dictum porttitor quis in libero. Etiam orci nulla, placerat eget sagittis ut, porta a dolor. Duis ac lacinia libero. Integer fermentum erat eget urna mollis tristique. Mauris et sapien leo. Suspendisse et lorem eget massa consectetur elementum eu ac neque. Nunc eu nisl tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque tristique, arcu sit amet commodo euismod, leo dolor sagittis ante, et fermentum nisi felis eu ipsum. Phasellus id elit lacus. Ut eget nisi non sapien tincidunt tristique eget vel neque. Nullam mi ipsum, blandit eget posuere a, mattis fermentum nunc. In a eros eget dui semper scelerisque a non neque. Curabitur aliquet tempus venenatis. Nam ante turpis, tincidunt at tristique vel, scelerisque ut libero.</p>

</section>
    <section id="fbsection4">
<br />
<blockquote class="bigquote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut massa ac mauris dictum porttitor quis in libero. Etiam orci nulla, placerat eget sagittis ut, porta a dolor. Duis ac lacinia libero. Integer fermentum erat eget urna mollis tristique. Mauris et sapien leo. Suspendisse et lorem eget massa consectetur elementum eu ac neque. Nunc eu nisl tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque tristique, arcu sit amet commodo euismod, leo dolor sagittis ante, et fermentum nisi felis eu ipsum. Phasellus id elit lacus. Ut eget nisi non sapien tincidunt tristique eget vel neque. Nullam mi ipsum, blandit eget posuere a, mattis fermentum nunc. In a eros eget dui semper scelerisque a non neque. Curabitur aliquet tempus venenatis. Nam ante turpis, tincidunt at tristique vel, scelerisque ut libero.</blockquote>
<br />
</section>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The simple answer is, you can't. There is no way possible to make an element's bg image flow out of it. It's like trying to see what's beyond the boundaries of a window to a house.

Comment: I see. That's a bummer! I wonder how the guys at Polygon managed to pull it off. Probably used some other div trick. Anyways, thank you so much for your input. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You can wrap it in another div and have the bg image attached to it, then it'll give the appearance of overflow but won't actually be.

Comment: I'm lost. It looks like your code does what you wanted. What did you want to see? I'm sure this must be doable.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Thanks for the reply, Kyle. I'm not sure what you mean by 'wrapping it' in another DIV. Does that mean I have to make a div OUTside of the parent, and somehow position the BG image to where I want it to show?
Ralph, The BG image shows inside the parent div, and is contained within the 700 px border. I want it to stretch out horizontally.. so the DIV, as a whole, kind of looks like a cross shape.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you can not make a background go outside of a div.

**The answer you are looking for**

I added a new div with an id: #backimage, I also assigned an id to your wrapper: #wrapper. I putted #backimage to a fixed position on the page. I also added a negative z-index so it will show behind the other divs (#wrapper in this case). Finally I added a background color to the #wrapper so content is more readable. Read the comments in the code for what does what.

```
 #backimage {
    position: fixed; /*if you make this position: absolute the background will scroll with the content*/
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background: url(http://solarle.cdn2.cafe24.com/tistory/i-beautiful.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    z-index: -100; /*low z-index so this div shows behind the other divs as background*/
}
#wrapper{
    background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.8); /*background-color of the wrappper so the image doesn t make the content unreadable*/
    margin: auto;
}
```

The full document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head> 
<style>
html, body, 
.container,
.cbp-fbscroller,
.cbp-fbscroller section { 
    height: 100%; 
}
 .cbp-fbscroller section {
    position: relative;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
 #backimage {
    position: fixed; /*if you make this position: absolute the background will scroll with the content*/
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background: url(http://solarle.cdn2.cafe24.com/tistory/i-beautiful.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    z-index: -100; /*low z-index so this div shows behind the other divs as background*/
}
#wrapper{
    background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.8); /*background-color of the wrappper so the image doesn t make the content unreadable*/
    margin: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
 <body>
 <div id="backimage"></div>
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 700px">
<div id="cbp-fbscroller" class="cbp-fbscroller">
    <section id="fbsection1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut massa ac mauris dictum porttitor quis in libero. Etiam orci nulla, placerat eget sagittis ut, porta a dolor. Duis ac lacinia libero. Integer fermentum erat eget urna mollis tristique. Mauris et sapien leo. Suspendisse et lorem eget massa consectetur elementum eu ac neque. Nunc eu nisl tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque tristique, arcu sit amet commodo euismod, leo dolor sagittis ante, et fermentum nisi felis eu ipsum. Phasellus id elit lacus. Ut eget nisi non sapien tincidunt tristique eget vel neque. Nullam mi ipsum, blandit eget posuere a, mattis fermentum nunc. In a eros eget dui semper scelerisque a non neque. Curabitur aliquet tempus venenatis. Nam ante turpis, tincidunt at tristique vel, scelerisque ut libero.</p>

</section>

    <section id="fbsection2">
<br />
<blockquote class="bigquote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut massa ac mauris dictum porttitor quis in libero. Etiam orci nulla, placerat eget sagittis ut, porta a dolor. Duis ac lacinia libero. Integer fermentum erat eget urna mollis tristique. Mauris et sapien leo. Suspendisse et lorem eget massa consectetur elementum eu ac neque. Nunc eu nisl tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque tristique, arcu sit amet commodo euismod, leo dolor sagittis ante, et fermentum nisi felis eu ipsum. Phasellus id elit lacus. Ut eget nisi non sapien tincidunt tristique eget vel neque. Nullam mi ipsum, blandit eget posuere a, mattis fermentum nunc. In a eros eget dui semper scelerisque a non neque. Curabitur aliquet tempus venenatis. Nam ante turpis, tincidunt at tristique vel, scelerisque ut libero.</blockquote>
<br />
</section>

    <section id="fbsection3">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut massa ac mauris dictum porttitor quis in libero. Etiam orci nulla, placerat eget sagittis ut, porta a dolor. Duis ac lacinia libero. Integer fermentum erat eget urna mollis tristique. Mauris et sapien leo. Suspendisse et lorem eget massa consectetur elementum eu ac neque. Nunc eu nisl tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque tristique, arcu sit amet commodo euismod, leo dolor sagittis ante, et fermentum nisi felis eu ipsum. Phasellus id elit lacus. Ut eget nisi non sapien tincidunt tristique eget vel neque. Nullam mi ipsum, blandit eget posuere a, mattis fermentum nunc. In a eros eget dui semper scelerisque a non neque. Curabitur aliquet tempus venenatis. Nam ante turpis, tincidunt at tristique vel, scelerisque ut libero.</p>

</section>
    <section id="fbsection4">
<br />
<blockquote class="bigquote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut massa ac mauris dictum porttitor quis in libero. Etiam orci nulla, placerat eget sagittis ut, porta a dolor. Duis ac lacinia libero. Integer fermentum erat eget urna mollis tristique. Mauris et sapien leo. Suspendisse et lorem eget massa consectetur elementum eu ac neque. Nunc eu nisl tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque tristique, arcu sit amet commodo euismod, leo dolor sagittis ante, et fermentum nisi felis eu ipsum. Phasellus id elit lacus. Ut eget nisi non sapien tincidunt tristique eget vel neque. Nullam mi ipsum, blandit eget posuere a, mattis fermentum nunc. In a eros eget dui semper scelerisque a non neque. Curabitur aliquet tempus venenatis. Nam ante turpis, tincidunt at tristique vel, scelerisque ut libero.</blockquote>
<br />
</section>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this answers your question.